# How to get custom UIView from Storyboard

Tags: uiview, storyboard

In FatEditViewController, has a custom UIView.

FatEditViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FatEditViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *myview;

@end
```

In another UIViewController, I want to get the myview object.
I do like this:

```
FatEditViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FatEdit"];
UIView *view = [vc myview];
NSLog(@"%@, %@", vc,view);
```

And the myview is null.
How to get the myview?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your myview gets instantiated only when your FatEditViewController's method viewDidLoad is called, which of course is called only when the view controller is presented on screen. One possible way to achieve what you need is to build myView programmatically (it wouldn't be an IBOutlet anymore), possibly by lazy initialising it in the getter. You would have to add the view to your FatEditViewController in the viewDidLoad method programmatically as well.

```
-(UIView *)myview
{
    if(!_myview){
        _myview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:whateverFrameYouNeed];
        //build the view
    }
    return _myview;
}
```

The property would have to be strong as well.